# Windows Authentication in ember.js

Tags: .net, windows, authentication, ember.js, ember-cli

I am developing an ember-cli application. Is it somehow possible to use Windows Authentication? In fact, i just need the logon name from Windows.

Perhaps, I could somehow wrap my ember-app into an ASP.NET MVC app and use Windows Authentication in that .NET application? Something like having just an index controller and return my ember app as a view?

Or is it possible to use ember-simple-auth with Windows Authentication?

Or could I build a WCF-Service which accepts user/passwords and sends back true or false... and then use this in my ember app, perhaps with ember-simple-auth and a custom authenticator?

Any ideas or examples?

I appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: JS can't determine windows username because of security. Wrapping your ember app isn't a good idea, but may work. Using ember-simple-auth with custom authenticator is good idea.

Comment: What is your backend?

Comment: I guess there might be sth. in Internet Explorer that might let you access the Windows auth from JS but that would of course only work with IE then.

Comment: My backend is .NET. Do you have an example of a custom authenticator in .NET? I couldn't find any example.

Comment: @marcoow It is possible to use ActiveX in IE. But it will not work in other browsers or on tablets...

Comment: @Lopo yeah, of course anything you build would only work in IE. You cannot build a custom authenticator in .NET - all authenticators (and all of Ember Simple Auth and Ember as well of course) are implemented in JS.

Comment: @marcoow Why can't I build an authentication service in .NET and use that in a custom authenticator in ember? imho, everything except ActiveX should work in all browsers, shouldn't it?

Comment: you can build an authentication service in .NET of course - "authenticators" as defined by Ember Simple Auth are part of the Ember app though and thus need to be implemented in JS of course.

Comment: OK, now I get your point. That's correct of course. I will try something with a custom .NET authentication service... thanks for your help.